# get(paste0(...)) overwrites results in R subarray

Tags: r

I have two subarrays and would like to sample one of them at random. The subarrays consist of character labels from a larger pool of labels as follows:

```
K <- as.character(1:10)
```

Suppose I call the arrays K1 and K2 and assign 10 labels between them as follows:

```
K1 <- 1:8
K2 <- 9:10
```

I then use

```
get(paste0("K", i))
```

to retrieve the labels that were sampled using a 'for' loop.

The issue I am having is this: if K1 is sampled, get(paste0("K", i)) returns labels from K2 (which contain labels 9:10) instead of returning K1 as needed.

In other words, I believe get(past0("K", i)) may be overwriting results.

Any thoughts on why this may occur and how to go about circumventing the issue?

Below is a more extensive example:

```
K <- 2
N <- 100
Hstar <- 10
perms <- 10000

probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar)

specs <- 1:N

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

K1 <- 1:8 # subarray 1
K2 <- 9:10 # subarray 2

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){ 
        if(i == 1){
            pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
        else{
            pop[j ,, 1] <- sample(haps[K1], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K1])
            pop[j ,, 2] <- sample(haps[K2], size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[K1]) 
        }
    }
}

HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

for(k in specs){
    for(j in 1:perms){
        for(i in 1:K){ 
            ind.index <- sample(specs, size = k, replace = FALSE)
            hap.plot <- pop[sample(1:nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ind.index, sample(i, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] 
            HAC.mat[j, k, i] <- length(unique(hap.plot))
        }
    }
}


means <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, mean)
lower <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.025))
upper <- apply(HAC.mat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.975))

d <- data.frame(specs, means, lower, upper)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

    if(i == 1){
        plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes",  ylim = c(1, Hstar))
        polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
        lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
        HAC.bar <- barplot(N*probs, xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = 1:Hstar)
}
else if(i > 1){
    plot(specs, means, type = "n", xlab = "Specimens sampled", ylab = "Unique haplotypes", ylim = c(1, Hstar))
    polygon(x = c(specs, rev(specs)), y = c(lower, rev(upper)), col = "gray")
    lines(specs, means, lwd = 2)
    HAC.bar <- barplot(N*probs[get(paste0("K", i))], xlab = "Unique haplotypes", ylab = "Specimens sampled", names.arg = get(paste0("K", i))) ## The issue may lie here
}
```

Any advice on what may be going on here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `get` won't (by itself) overwrite anything. So something else is happening, but it is impossible to tell what that might be without seeing a more complete code example. More broadly, though, `get(paste(...))` is typically not a great approach for anything. R has named lists for a reason! :)

Comment: @joran I have added a more extensive example to my original post.

Comment: Your example seems to run fine for me, after I fixed a typo near the top. I'm not sure what you think is wrong.

Comment: @joran if you look at what is in the 'pop' variable, it is populated with labels 1:8. The barplot should reflect this, but it doesn't. Instead, it plots data for labels 9:10. get(paste0("K", i)) returns "9" "10" instead of "1" "2" ... "8". I need get(paste0("K", i)) to return the subarray that was randomly sampled instead of the last subarray each time. Also, what typo was there?

Comment: In the first set of loops you wrote `probs[K1]` twice, I think you meant `probs[K2]` on the second one. I think you're just confused about the final for loop. You set up only two plotting regions with `mfrow` and then you plot in them once (`i == 1`) and then you _overplot_ them with `i == 2`. So you're just never seeing the first plot.

Comment: (Also, don't put `else` on a new line. It can be a syntax error, depending on how you run the code.)

Comment: @joran Yes I did mean K2, thanks! Actually, my intent is for only one set of plots is to be created because my algorithm either selects K1 or K2 at random.

Comment: Ok, then remove that final for loop and you're good.

Comment: @joran You mean remove the else() part of the last for loop? I still need R to produce the correct plots.

Comment: The for loop will always plot the the graphs in the `if` clause first and then _overplot_ them with the graphs in the `else` clause. If you only want one or the other, remove the `for` loop and make the `if` condition dependent on the correct value.

Comment: @joran The sounds like the correct fix, although I am not a programmer by training, so I am learning along the way. Then, simply having only an if() statement along with an else if() should do the trick?

Comment: @joran I tried removing the loop, but  get the exact same results - conflicting plots. I've edited my post so that you can see what I did. Thanks.

Comment: I'm really at a loss here. Your edit is sort of nonsensical. One condition based on the value of `i` and one on `K`? Huh? You haven't clearly stated under what circumstances you want the graphs in the first block plotted and when you want the graphs in the second block plotted. Once you figure that out, write the `if` condition appropriately.

Comment: @joran Yes, I meant i not K... sorry. Also I changed the else{} statement in the first for loop to an else if() statement. Unfortunately, it gives the same incorrect results. The curve is correct, but the barplot is for labels 9 and 10 instead of 1:8 as it should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156490/discussion-between-joran-and-jarrett-phillips).